# How to generate RenderScript ScriptC* files with Android.mk?

Tags: android, renderscript

I have the following project structure

```
/-src/mypackage/myscript.rs
|              |MyClass.java
/Android.mk
```

How to write proper Android.mk file to build this project (or just to generate renderscript ScriptC* files)?

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to add .rs files to your LOCAL_SRC_FILES.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the AOSP-style Android.mk platform build, you can do something like:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src) $(call all-renderscript-files-under, src)
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent for `Android.bp`?